# Can I customize the volume image of an individual USB drive?

Tags: finder, usb, icon

When I plug in my USB key, I see this icon on my desktop:

[image: removable disk]

**I want to customize this, so that the image on the desktop and in Finder will look like the physical USB key.**

I was able to find an online image converter to create an icon from  my image, and I was able to successfully use the "get info, copy icon, paste icon".  As you can see, the far right info window is for the icon itself, and I've copy-pasted that image the middle info window, which is a folder:
[image: copied icon to folder icon]

Applying that same copy-paste technique to the drive itself (the far-left info window), I get completely different results:
[image: copied icon to volume icon]

What am I doing wrong here?  After an hour spent trying to troubleshoot this (messing with SetFile, manually copying the .VolumeIcon.icns file, etc), I also need to ask: is what I'm attempting even possible?

(I looked at a program called CandyBar, but it would have changed the image for ALL drives, not individual drives; it doesn't help me)

Here's what happens when I tried dragging an .icns file onto the drive icon:
[image: no love with icns files]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-partitioned and re-formatted the drive to the exact same file system (one partition, Fat32), and now it works.  Magically.  (I even restored all the files that were on the USB drive at the time of the problem.)

I have no idea what the problem was or if it will happen again, but the drive is now showing the proper icon.

Answer (score 2):

Create an icon file (.icns) from your PNG image. To create the icon file use Icon Composer.app (if you already have it) or use the new, officially sanctioned tool `iconutil` as described in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11660736/xcode-4-4-removed-icon-composer-in-developer-tools). After creating the icon file drag/drop the file onto the drive's file info window, same as you did with the PNG file.

Comment: It [still doesn't work](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JGNTS.png).  Admittedly, I used an online converter because I'm too lazy to make that many images and use the command line tool.  Could that be the problem here?  Again, this icon file works in other folders... just not this drive.

Comment: Read this short article. http://macapper.com/2007/04/21/how-to-create-custom-icons-for-your-mac/. The important part is "Icon Composer leaves us with an ICNS file, which is almost usable. We now need to convert the ICNS to a RSRC file, which can be easily done with Icns2Rsrc. Just open the app, open the ICNS file, and it will ask you where to save the RSRC."

Comment: It looks like [Icns2Rsrc doesn't exist anymore](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/11781), and when looking for an alternate download link I got [referred back to the original website that I used to create the ICNS file](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1311386).

Answer (score 2):

Image2icns may be able to help you. Here's a link: http://www.img2icnsapp.com/